# How do I print my book using Indesign cs6 and have the pages come out in the right order?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, print-design

I am trying to print my `4" x 6"` book from InDesign CS6 to my home printer. The book has about 100 pages, a perfect bound book with a few front pages and a table of contents.

I want to print the pages in the right order as 2up, centered & double-sided, onto `8.5" x 11"` paper which I will then have cut down into individual `4" x 6"` pages and bind by hand. The document has facing pages and I am using "print booklet",e selected 2-up perfect bound and, since my printer doesn't have automatic duplexing, I am printing the odd pages first then turning the paper over and printing the even pages.

I've got everything working except the order of the pages does not make any sense and I can't figure out why or how to fix it. I did not anticipate this being a complex function! I thought that "print booklet" would handle the page ordering.

Comment: Is your number of pages divisible by 4? "about" 100 isn't clear enough. 100, 104, 108, 96, 92, 88 will work. But 102, 103, 101, 99, 98, will all throw off the page order.

Comment: it's 101 pages exactly. but i'm okay with having blank pages. i wondered if the signature size being 4 would affect me - and it sounds like what you are asking might mean it does? i'll mess with it and get it divisible by 4 and see if that works! thank you, fingers crossed.

Comment: +1 to @Scott and I just wanted to add if you ever plan to send your book to a professional printer they also **require** the book to be divisible by four.

Answer (score 5):

Any book or booklet printed **must** have a page count **divisible by 4 at a minimum**.

You have a left page and right page on the front, and a left page and right page on the back, totaling 4 pages. This is called a **signature**. A signature is one sheet of stock/paper with many pages (or folios) on it. When the signature is folded and/or cut it creates the proper pages.

If you do not have a page count divisible by 4, then you need to add blank pages, or delete pages, to make the page count divisible by 4.

It doesn't matter where you add blank pages or delete pages from, but the indesign document **must have the correct page count for the signature**.

The overal pages panel should look similar to this for a facing pages document (with the correct number of pages of course):

[image]

To use Indesign's Print Booklet feature, and be able ot print even/odd pages independently follow these steps:

1. Print to a postscript file

   - Choose print booklet
   - Click the Print Settings button
   - Set the Printer drop down to Postscript file.
   - Make certain all other print settings are correct such as bleeds, rotation, scale, etc.
2. Open the resulting .ps (postscript) file with Adobe Acrobat.
3. Acrobat will distill the .ps to a .pdf file.
4. Save the PDF
5. Print even/odd pages from the PDF in Acrobat.

Comment: This is excellent and all makes sense and I greatly appreciate it. I have facing pages but page 1 sits at the beginning as one page all alone - I think this also is going to affect the page order. Any clues for me there? Or I can ask in another post. You've been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: All pages in the document count. if you have 101 pages currently, just add 3 blank pages to the end of the document. The last page, in a facing pages document, should look like the opposite of the first page in the document, i.e. page 1 right size, page 104 left side.

Comment: I deleted one page so there'd be 100. But this first page still sits by itself, no matter how I move things around, or even if I add pages.

Comment: That's fine. The important factor is the actual number of pages. In facing pages documents, page 1 is always by itself. It's assumed it's the title page or cover. The last page in the file will be the back cover. And it too should be by itself rather than in a spread.

Comment: oh, super cool!! how do i give you a vote or something like that? i'm new to this forum.

Comment: You can click the up arrow on the left. And if this solves your problem and answers your question, you can click the check mark to the left of my post. :)

Comment: so fixing the total number of pages has solved one part of the problem. but i must not be selecting quite the right print setting. when i print odd pages first, then even (which i'm only able to do if i save the original indesign file to pdf, then i'm not using print booklet anymore - i don't seem to be able to select pages, range of pages or sequence when i'm trying to print directly from "print booklet" in indesign) it's still slightly out of order. not to the degree it was before, but it's still off. any ideas?

Comment: @Lisa see my updated answer.

Comment: it's still not working! everything you say make sense and i think the issue is that i need this ready for PERFECT binding. i tried removing facing pages used single pages then saved to pdf - but it's still not working. it seems like it's printing consecutive pages on one side, and then consecutive pages on the other side, but it's still not lining up front to back.

Comment: You can choose 2-up Perfect Bound in the Print Booklet screen. And I don't understand "lining up". Is the page order correct? Are you trying to align the front and back side of the paper?

Comment: You can't register both sides of print from a home printer. The paper shifts a little with every print. You could spend weeks and never get a perfectly aligned front and back side.

Comment: when i say lining up i'm still talking about the page order. page order is still not happening. i'm trying all the options i can think of. 2 up, consecutive, then saving to pdf and it's still off. divisible by four has helped but it's still not coming out in the right order.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know how to assist any further. Everything I've posted should work. The only possible thing I could think of is you aren't turning the paper in the right direction when printing the second side.

Comment: thanks very much for your help, i really appreciate it. i think the final solution incorporates everything you are suggesting plus probably some little thing i can't figure out..

Comment: Dead thread probably, but this sounds like the printout is in "reader spreads" rather than "printer spreads" (or it is in printer spreads but the OP is misunderstanding the need for it). Reader spreads are typically how something is worked on in indesign. Printer spreads are the same pages re-arranged so that you can (more or less) print it out and fold it and the page order will be correct: in other words the top of the stack is the innermost pages and the bottom of the stack is the covers.

Answer (score 2):

I did this without making a postscript file, right from InDesign. From the Print Booklet window, click on Print Settings. Then, click on Printer in the next window that comes up, and from the drop down list, select Paper Handling. There, you can select odd or even only, then flip over your stack of pages and print on the other side. Also, InDesign will add in extra pages if it is not divisible by 4, but you won't have control over where.

Answer (score 0):

Your book needs to have a total page count that can be divided by 4 for a 2up, or 8 for a 4up.

Example: Instead of 101 pages, use 104 pages by adding 3 extra white pages at the end of your file.

> **Additionally**, don't forget to use the "Print blank pages" or "Print blank Printer Spread"; some software will have this option and if left unchecked, it will ignore
>   the blank pages... which will cause your pages to not be printed in the right order. This is a mistake a lot of people do.

Also, to correct the answer above, it's better to open a postscript .ps with **Adobe Acrobat Distiller** directly (drag and drop); it's easier to select which profile to use and the quality of the PDF. You can build your own profiles or create new ones.

**If I'm not mistaken, the "standard" setting is not high resolution and that's the one used when dragging the .ps on Acrobat Reader or Pro.** So be careful!

---

If nothing works as planed, you can always export a PDF and simply create your own 'imposition' by inserting each PDF page back into an Indesign document already 2ups.

Sometimes it's the only way to get the perfect margins and not waste time trying to figure out how to print your booklets perfectly. Plus it's easier to re-print a few pages this way if you ever made a mistake while doing your manual "duplexing"! It's something you only need to do once, then whenever you'll update the PDF, the pages will get updated automatically.