# Help to print book with 8/5x11 pages on 11x17 booklet in reader spread?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs5

I have an Adobe book. The book has five files with each page being 8.5 X 11. I want to print the entire book, on 11X17 in reader sequence. How do I do that?

Art

Comment: Hi Art, and welcome to GD. Have you searched for any instructions on Google? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18272/how-do-i-print-my-book-using-indesign-cs6-and-have-the-pages-come-out-in-the-rig?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

First merge the files into one and then use the print booklet feature under the file menu to print the booklet in a way that is ready to be printed in a way that is foldable. Now I'm assuming you're working with a relatively small number of pages. If not please update your question with more details.