# How do I set pages in the right order for a perfect bound book in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, binding

2 documents.

1st is the front and back covers.

2nd document is the 56 pages of the booklet I want to create.

I would like to print these pages and *perfectly bind the book by hand.*
Is there a way to set the pages in the correct order in Indesign? I have been told that I would need to create **signatures** and that these will go inside the book. How do I tell Indesign to make these signatures in the correct order?

from what I have read here:
[How do I print my book using Indesign cs6 and have the pages come out in the right order?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18272/how-do-i-print-my-book-using-indesign-cs6-and-have-the-pages-come-out-in-the-rig)

This person is trying to do the same and **2-up Perfect Bound does not work.**

Comment: What doesn't work about "2-up Perfect Bound"?

Comment: The correct order for pages in a perfect bound book is generally the same as reading order! You print single pages double sided, that's it. Perfect binding *can* be done by sewing signatures together then glueing but since you are binding this yourself there's no need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect (sometimes called double-fan) binding does not require signatures, but rather creates a text block for the book from single, unfolded pages.  It is a process for applying glue to the binding edges of loose pages to join them with glue only. I am worried that you might be confusing perfect binding with another type of binding.

To print sheets for a perfect binding, create page spreads when you setup the InDesign document, and format normally.  When you print, let InDesign know to setup for a 2-sided print job.  If you have issues with getting InDesign to print, just export the .idd as a high quality .pdf of single sheets, and print as a 2-sided document.

Comment: Perfect binding *can* be combined with signatures sewn together then glued.