# how to set up file to make a 100 page 5.5"x8.5" book that i will print on letter paper and bind with japanese stab binding

Tags: adobe-indesign

i am wanting to print a book at home on regular letter paper, then cut all the pages in half and put one half on top of the other and bind it using japanese stab binding.  does anyone know how i can set this file up?  thanks so much for any help you can give!

Comment: I don't think there is much of a setup. Is there anything specific that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my book using Indesign cs6 and have the pages come out in the right order?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18272/how-do-i-print-my-book-using-indesign-cs6-and-have-the-pages-come-out-in-the-rig)

Comment: @Luciano I don’t see how that’s a duplicate of this. It’s asking for a completely different setup…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet design a booklet in Indesign / print at home / cut / bind by hand. The main difference is the binding type, the rest is almost the same process. Scott's answer has the main setup for the file. OP here didn't specify exactly what else they need.

Comment: @Luciano No, the main difference is that this question is not about printing a booklet. Say you have a 100-page document. What Lindsey is looking for is this: print the document, 2-sided, so that the first sheet has page 1 top-front, page 2 top-back, page 51 bottom-front, and page 52 bottom-back, etc. Unless there’s some setting I’m unaware of, I don’t think that’s possible with booklet printing.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't know how booklet printing works in Indesign, but you are describing the output obtained with booklet printing in Adobe Acrobat Reader (see [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-booklets-acrobat-reader.html)).

Comment: @Paolo No, that output is different from what I’m talking about. Booklet imposition will **rotate** each page 90° on the printed page, which does not seem to be what the question is asking for here. I may have misunderstood what Lindsey is after, but it looked to me as if it’s about getting two landscape pages on top of each other on the same page, in order. I can’t get booklet printing to do that in InDesign or Acrobat.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I see. The question is: does Lindsay want the book printed on both the faces of the page (i.e. booklet), or on single face (i.e. print on two columns)? In both the cases, if the goal is have two pages on a face (to be cut in half), we need a rotation of 90°.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini The way I understood it, (s)he wants to lay out the text in half-letter-sized landscape mode, then stack two pages on top of each other on a letter-sized page, which will then be printed (on both sides of the paper). Then the printed pages will be cut in two vertical half-letter-sized parts, and the upper part simply placed on top of the lower part for a whole book. There’s no rotation involved in that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no automated way to do this.

The easiest way I can think of to do it is the following:

1. Make a document (with facing pages) at the the trim size you want to end up with (i.e., 5.5″ × 8.5″), and then lay out the whole book exactly how you want it to end up looking in this document. This will be your *layout document*.
2. Once everything is finished, create a new document at Letter size (also with facing pages). This will be your *imposition document*.
3. Use [Scott Zanelli’s *MultiPageImporter* script](https://github.com/mike-edel/ID-MultiPageImporter) to place the layout document into the imposition document: set the page range to be **the first half of the pages, rounding up to the nearest even number** and the positioning to the upper left corner. Then place the layout document once more, this time selecting the rest of the pages and setting the positioning to be the bottom left corner.

Once you’ve done this, you should end up with a document where each Letter-sized imposition page contains two layout pages from the book: at the top, page `X`; and at the bottom, page `(total number of pages / 2) + X`.

So if your book has a total of 135 layout pages, the first time you run the script, you choose pages 1 to 68; the second time, you choose pages 69 to 134. You will then end up with a document where imposition page 1 contains layout page 1 at the top and layout page 69 at the bottom; imposition page 7 contains layout pages 7 and 76; etc. The last imposition page will contain layout page 68 at the top and be blank at the bottom.

4. On the first page in the imposition document, make a new layer, on which you add a thin, grey line across the page exactly halfway down. Then lock the layer (just in case).
5. Do a 2-sided print of the imposition document.
6. Once printed, stack the papers very carefully and use a guillotine to cut the stack along the thin grey line. Place the upper half on top of the lower half and you should be good to go.

---

<sup>Note:</sup>

<sup>This is all assuming your artwork does not need to extend to the trim edges anywhere. If you have any artwork that does and you still want the trim size to be 5.5″ × 8.5″, things get more complicated. You’ll have to add bleed to your layout document, and you’ll have to print it on paper that’s bigger than Letter, since you’ll have to have the bleed on the page before cutting as well.</sup>